# Changing the Python icon in Alt-Tab/Ubuntu sidebar

Tags: python, tkinter, icons

When I write something in Python it puts this icon in the Ubuntu sidebar and in the alt tab list:

[image]

Is there any way to change it, in either `python/pygame/tkinter`?

Comment: Is this Pygame, Tkinter, or a command line application?

Comment: I am writing a game in pygame at the minute, but would like to know how it works for all of them.  Things are run from the command line.

Comment: Does [this](http://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/display.html#pygame.display.set_icon) work?

Comment: no. That makes a surface the size of the icon.